# What fraction of this equilateral triangle is shaded?

Tags: geometry

choose the correct option[image]

My attempts  :  i applied formula of equilateral  triangle$ = \sqrt 3/ 4 a^2 $and area  of sector $=  \theta/360 \pi r^2$ but  here  im confused  how  i  can find the area of shaded portion

any hints/solution thanks

Comment: @ThomasShelby  but my answer is not  matching with all option,,so im confused

Comment: "Choose the correct option" is an intolerably poor choice of title. Please put a little more effort into choosing an informative title for your question next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Here $r=a/2$ and there're three sections.

So,area of the shaded portion
$$A' = \frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2-3\cdot\frac{60}{360}\cdot\frac{\pi a^2}{4}$$ $$A' = \frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2-\frac{\pi a^2}{8}= \frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2\bigg(1-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}\bigg) = A\bigg(1-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}\bigg)$$

Comment: thanks @AK19....

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality wwe may assume that the side of  the equilateral triangle is $2$

The area of the three circular regions is half the circle of radius $1$ so  it is $\pi/2$

The total area of the triangle with side $2$ is $\sqrt { 3}$.

Thus the ratio of the shaded area is $$1-\frac {\pi}{2\sqrt {3}}$$ which is option $1$